# Why is my Graphics2D Font changing randomly?

Tags: java, fonts, graphics2d

I have the Font "Minecraft" loaded into a static Font object in the Loader class. It gets generated when the program starts and never changes.
I have multiple Screens. Each of them accesses the Font object and defines the Font of the String with:

> g2.setFont(Loader.font)

Everything worked fine.
But as soon as I use the same procedure for the new Start class, the Font just goes back to the default font. On every screen. If I check the name of the font via:

> System.out.println(Loader.font.getName());

I get the correct font name ("Minecraft") as output.

I really have no clue why this would happend. How can I fix this or what is the error?

([Here a short video if it wasn´t clear what my problem is](https://streamable.com/x31xfv))

Comment: It depends on where you're calling setFont. You need to show a minimal, reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: I am working on it. But I am not really sure if this is reproducible. Since it just randomly happend in this class but not in the others.

Comment: IT sounds like you have a different graphics context, are you using the exact same reference to `g2` to do all the text in your application? If not, then you need to use `graphics.setFont(Loader.font);` every time you make/reference a new graphics context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was acually pretty simple to fix.
I just wasn´t rapainting my JPanel. Somehow everything but the Font got painted automatically. I have no clue why. And I am still confused.
At least the problem is fixed now.